# Advice on making a jet engine

Tags: jet-engine, jet, engine-design

I'm a software engineer and recently want to make a jet engine myself. Since I am a newbie in this period, I want to know what basic knowledge is needed for making the engine. I wish to use it on my radio control aircraft, which has a 1.6m wing-span.
Hope someone can give some advice. Really appreciate.

Comment: Lets use an analogy. If a hobbyist software engineer came to you and said "I want to design a search system on par with Google, and just as fast" what would your advice be? (hint: walk before you run). Perhaps start with looking at designs for other scale-model engines before diving in yourself. See what improvements you could make to existing designs.

Comment: "I want to make a perfect one as much as possible..."    Does that stand in contrast to the early jet-engine designers, with decades of engineering experience, whom you seem to suppose must have set their standards lower?  Do you think that early jet engines exploded because the engineers who designed them thought that was okay and didn't aspire to "a perfect one as much as possible"?

Comment: You can find instructions and plans on the internet for making your own pulsejet engine. Like [this one from Popular Mechanics](http://www.popularmechanics.com/home/how-to-plans/how-to/a6549/how-to-build-a-pulse-jet/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you'll need to know machining (use of end mills, lathes,  welding, etc), structural mechanical design (statics, dynamics, strength of materials, bearings, machine elements), heat transfer, thermodynamics, and control systems. It's a lot for a beginner. I'd recommend starting with something easier. For example, design and build a small robot to vacuum your floor. Or design and build a radio controlled car or boat from scratch. Any type of project like this will be challenging and help you learn what you need for a bigger project.

Comment: Ok, Although it seems hard to begin, but I'm sure I will study them in my spare time. Thanks a lot.